# How can I change the keyboard layout on the hardware/system/bios level?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is there any way to change the keyboard layout on the hardware/system/bios level?

**e.g.:**

Say, when asked for the system password on boot you could use the dvorak(or any other) layout to type in instead of the default qwerty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An actual Dvorak keyboard reports the same letters to the BIOS with the same [scan-codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode), and should work fine.

If you're using a non-Dvorak keyboard with a software overlay to make it act like a Dvorak, then, no you'll need software running to provide that overlay, and it won't be running at the BIOS level.

Comment: Couldn't you (in theory) change the scan codes that are released from the keyboard?  Not an easy task, I should think, but with time I expect it could be done?  No?